Snowflake Connector. Call list as parameter for IN filter
OUTLINE
I'm using Snowflake Connector to pull data from a Snowflake database into my Python notebook.
I have parameters stored separately that are pulled into my query which is stored as an f-string.
I can pull in parameters for use in filters if they contain a single variable:
myvar = 'foo'    

myquery = f"""    
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE VAR1 = '{myvar}'
"""   

cursor = sf_connection.cursor()  
try:
    df= cursor.execute(myquery).fetch_pandas_all()
finally:
    cursor.close()

PROBLEM
I want to store a list and use it within an IN statement in the query:
mylist = ['foo','bar']   

myquery  = f"""     
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE VAR1 IN '{mylist}'    
"""

However, the above errors.
CURRENT SOLUTION
I can index each element of the list within the query and it functions:
mylist = ['foo','bar'] 

myquery  = f"""     
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE VAR1 IN ('{mylist[0]}', '{mylist[1]}')    
"""

This isn't a workable solution as I need to be able to alter the mylist parameter and still have the query function.
